# How to apply a list of ApplyChangesOperation on a Roslyn Workspace

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a set of **ApplyChangesOperation**, which I want to apply to a **Workspace** in a loop.
All the operations operate on a single file.

Something like:

```
//Filter out a set of ApplyChangesOperation as applychangesoperations
//These changes all apply to one file with name filename
foreach (var op in applychangesoperations)
{
    op.Apply(workspace, CancellationToken.None);
}

//Assuming all these operations apply to one file
var myNewDoc = workspace.GetDocument(fileName);
var myNewDocText = await newDoc.GetTextAsync();
```

When I do this, I only get the last change which was applied to the workspace is in myNewDocText.

Is there a way I can apply the whole list of changes I have in 
applychangesoperations to the workspace and extract the text of the updated file?